# Android: ruta de imagen a Bitmap

Tags: android

Tengo un problema, en un JSON traigo unos datos e imagenes, lo que quiero hacer es pasar esas rutas de imagenes a Bitmaps para setearsetas a GridView, mi duda es como paso la ruta de la imagen a Bitmap.
Este es mi JSON

> {
>      'code':'OK',
>      'data':{
>         'folio':12345,
>         'customer':'Jose Trinidad Ramos Trejo',
>         'delivered':'2016/10/30',
>         'images':[
>         'http://kuixx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Paisajes-5.jpg','http://www.paisajesbonitos.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/paisajes-bonitos-de-primavera-verde-lago-agua-natural-animales.jpg','https://wallpapershqpacks.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/049.jpg'
>         ]
>      }
>   }

Si ustedes copian la ruta de las imagenes los llevara a ella

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tal como te respondi en la pregunta anterior puedes llamar a esta funcion

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String url_image) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(url_image);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        Log.e("Bitmap","returned");
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        Log.e("Exception",e.getMessage());
        return null;
    }
}
```

Y a esta funcion le envias las imagenes que obtienes en tu json

```
Bitmap bitMapFromJson = getBitmapFromURL(json.getString('images'));
```

Comment: OK, deja lo checo

Comment: Si me funciono, muchas gracias sioesi

Comment: Agradesco tus respuestas

Comment: Claro que si sioesi

Comment: @Javierfr :) saludos

Comment: sioesi me surgio una dudasi ves que yo tengo la ruta y despues la paso a Bitmap, es posible que le setee la ruta de cada imagen al GridView? o es correcto pasarlo a Bitmap primero?

Comment: Me parece que la mejor opcion que tienes es pasarlo a Bitmap, una consulta.. estas trabajando aun con el array de imagenes o ahora las transformas 1 por 1? Porque la respuesta de Elenasys es igual a la mia, solo que el te dio la solucion del jsonArray pero yo tenia entendido que estabas trabajando ya solo con 1 por una?

Comment: Las imagenes las obtengo como el ejemplo de Elenasys y cuando las envio itero en un for el arrayList que contiene las imagenes para enviarlas de una por una.

Comment: Perfecto! Suerte con eso espero que te haya servido mi respuesta, saludos!

Comment: Gracias a ti sioesi por estarme ayudando. :D

Answer (score 1):

Para obtener las rutas de imágenes, según tu estructura tienes un objeto y dentro otro que contiene un array llamado `images`, para esto debes acceder al Array y para almacenar las url de imagen puedes crear un arraylist:

```
  String contenidoJson = "{ 'code':'OK', 'data':{ 'folio':12345, 'customer':'Jose Trinidad Ramos Trejo', 'delivered':'2016/10/30', 'images':[ 'http://kuixx.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/01/Paisajes-5.jpg','http://www.paisajesbonitos.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/12/paisajes-bonitos-de-primavera-verde-lago-agua-natural-animales.jpg','https://wallpapershqpacks.files.wordpress.com/2013/04/049.jpg' ] } }";

        //crea lista para almacenar imagenes.
        List<String> listaImagenes = new ArrayList<String>();

        try {
            JSONObject mainObject = new JSONObject(contenidoJson);
            JSONObject objectData = mainObject.getJSONObject("data");
            JSONArray imagenes = objectData.getJSONArray("images");
            for (int i=0; i < imagenes.length(); i++) {
              //Agrega imagenes.
              listaImagenes.add(imagenes.get(i).toString());
            }

        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

Teniendo tu lista de imágenes puedes obtener el bitmap a partir de la url mediante este [método](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8993175/250260):

```
public static Bitmap getBitmapFromURL(String src) {
    try {
        URL url = new URL(src);
        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setDoInput(true);
        connection.connect();
        InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
        Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
        return myBitmap;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // Log exception
        return null;
    }
}
```

al obtener el `bitmap` puedes agregarlo en un `ImageView` sin problema.

Comment: Si Elenasys efectivamente asi es como lo tengo estructurado, agradesco tu respuesta.